# Is there a recommended way of doing post request in android?

Tags: android, http-post

Is there a recommended way of doing post request in android? because before I use `HttpPost` and `HttpClient` for executing post request but these classes are now deprecated in API level 22.

Comment: You can use Volley or else UrlConnection manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, they are deprecated. You can use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) which is recommended by Google Dev.

> Volley offers the following benefits:
>   Automatic scheduling of network requests.
>   Multiple concurrent network connections.
>   Transparent disk and memory response caching with standard HTTP cache coherence.
>   Support for request prioritization.
>   Cancellation request API. You can cancel a single request, or you can set blocks or scopes of requests to cancel.
>   Ease of customization, for example, for retry and backoff.
>   Strong ordering that makes it easy to correctly populate your UI with data fetched asynchronously from the network.

Volley is very easy to use:

```
// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url ="http://www.google.com";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
}
});
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

```
 public  String makeRequest(String pageURL, String params)
{
    String result = null;
    String finalURL =pageURL;
    Logger.i("postURL", finalURL);
    Logger.i("data", params);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(finalURL);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(params.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        os.close();
        int HttpResultCode =urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(HttpResultCode ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            result = convertStreamToString(in);
            Logger.i("API POST RESPONSE",result);
        }else{
            Logger.e("Error in response ", "HTTP Error Code "+HttpResultCode +" : "+urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then converting your stream to string

```
 private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Create your JSON

```
JSONObject j=new JSONObject();
        try {
            j.put("name","hello");
            j.put("email","hello@gmail.com");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  //Call the method
        makeRequest("www.url.com",j.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another possible library that could help you: [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

With an example post from their webseite:

```
public static final MediaType JSON
= MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String post(String url, String json) throws IOException {
  RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .post(body)
      .build();
  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

Or [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

You basically create an interface with annotations about the rest API and parameters you are calling, and can receive the parsed json model like this:

```
public interface MyService {
    @POST("/api")
    void createTask(@Body CustomObject o, Callback<CustomObject > cb);
}
```

You can set them both also up together, here is a guide that helped me a lot: https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client/

Even though this is not the official way recommended in the google docs, these are nice libraries, worth taking a look into.